# How to have my accessibility app overlay other apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, accessibility

I'm working on an accessibility app for a client and he needs it to be able to have it on top of other apps. It takes a small area and can be moved easily.

Is there an app permission or config setting to do this?

**UPDATE:**
An iPad owner sent me a screenshot showing a chat app floating on top of another app.

Comment: Nope, not possible in iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy Shirley it's possible for accessibility?

Comment: No.  Apps cannot operate outside their sandbox. There are a lot of accessibility features built in to iOS by Apple and these can add overlays and manipulate the screen image but an app cannot, no matter what its intention or purpose.

Comment: It is possible on newer iPads. Someone sent me a screenshot. One app is floating over another.

Comment: You need to post the screen shot if you want better answers. My guess is that the “floating” chat app is in Slide Over, which is a standard iPad multitasking feature. Check out the [Slide Over and Split View Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

No, its is not possible because apple does not even give you permission to show you wallpaper too... if it does have given that feature then any app could have a possible access to some some secure data situationally.

e.g: You are using payment gateway in an app now another app start running as an overlay over the existing app which means having a snap shot of the previous app as a background of your current app. Hence privacy breaching. Hence apple will not approve of something like that, hence no feature like that.

Hope this will help you to understand more clearly.

Comment: That may have been true up to recently. I think they may have enable it in the last few updates. I have a screenshot of an chat app floating above another app on an iPad.

Comment: then we have to check

Comment: it's true apple doesn't allow setting wallpaper, but setting wallpaper and reading wallpaper are not related at all. What I mean by downvoting is that the reasoning is flawed.